# How to find the lastIndexOf if Array.includes returns true?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays

`let arr1 = ['Red, 'Blue', 'Black', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Black']`

`let arr2 = ['Black', 'White', 'Green']`

I am writing below function to check if `arr1` includes `arr2` value

```
function findCommonElements(arr1, arr2) { 
return arr1.some(item => arr2.includes(item))
}
```

my function is working fine and it returns `true` since `arr1` includes **Black**, but I want to know the **lastIndexOf** position of matched value if `findCommonElements` returns `true`

Comment: What code have you attempted to solve this new problem?

Comment: And what's your question this? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to replace lastIndexOf value with new value, but it is not possible without knowing the lastIndexOf position, in my case I want ```arr1``` to be ```['Red, 'Blue', 'Black', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'White']```

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in the comment section. Rather edit your question to contain all relevant information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do but this function will return 5 (the index of 'Black' in arr1)

```
function findCommonElements(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.reduce((a, item, i) =>  arr2.includes(item) ? i : a  , -1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and `includes` (note: find will short-circuit the loop if it finds a match - it won't progress any further so all you'll be guaranteed is one match or no match), and then, if `found` return the last index of `found`.

```js
const arr1 = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Black'];
const arr2 = ['Black', 'White', 'Green'];

function findIndexOfCommon(arr1, arr2) { 
  const found = arr1.find(el => arr2.includes(el));
  if (found) return arr1.lastIndexOf(found);
  return undefined;
}

const index = findIndexOfCommon(arr1, arr2);

if (index) arr1[index] = 'White';

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ar1 = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Black', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Black'];
let ar2 = ['Black', 'White', 'Green'];

function findMatch(array_1_small, array2_large) { //first parameter must be smallest array
var ary = new Array();
for(i = 0;i < array2_large.length; i++)
{
  for(z = 0; z < array_1_small.length; z++)
  {
    if(array2_large[i] == array_1_small[z])
    {
      ary.push(i);
    }
  }

}
return ary;}

findMatch(ar2, ar1) //first parameter must be smallest array
```

findMatch will return `[2, 5]` from this array you can get last matched index